# Importing external library (say pytube) in Django

Tags: django

Fairly new to Django. I am trying to import Pytube to my django project. I am on my virtual environment and installed pytube va Pip. How to I import it. not working the way like 'from Pytube import Youtube'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from` and `import` is case sensitive. Try `from pytube import YouTube`. Packages are usually lowercase

Comment: I mean yes, I did that say in views.py and having this error "unresolved import 'pytube'Python(unresolved-import)"

Comment: checked via pip freeze while in virtual environment 'pytube==9.6.0' so i think it is installed correctly

Comment: Do you start the server also while venv is activated?

Comment: Yes. It's working perfectively fine. until I do 'from pytube import YouTube'. server stops with error 'ImportError: cannot import name 'quote' from 'pytube.compat' (..............\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\compat.py)'

Comment: Ok I think I know whats the problem now. firstly fun `pip uninstall pytube' and then 'pip install pytube3' all on activated venv - and then try running the server

Comment: I did my course of Django and I have everything working from front end and to backend. But I am not sure how to import external packages/libraries in django like pytube and call it in my apps

Comment: All you're doing is perfectly fine and thats the way to do in the problem is purely on python. You're trying to import part of the package that does not exist.

Comment: Okay. so I did pip install pytube3 and now the server is not crashing. let me see if my code works now. thanks, quqa123!!!!

Comment: No problem :) and next time you ask question here just try to add the code and errors you're getting and it will be easier to resolve. Don't forget to 'like' comments or anwsers that are useful to you so other can have better access to it.

Comment: fairly new to stack overflow as well :). I am a financial auditor!!